# Question on homogeneous spaces.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M=G/H$ be a reductive homogeneous space, i.e. we assume that $G$ is a Lie group and $H \subset G$ a closed subgroup such that the Lie algebra $g$ of $G$ splits as $g= h \oplus m$ with $\mbox{Ad}(H)m=m$ and we furthermore have an $\mbox{Ad}(H)$-invariant scalar product $(.,.)$ on $m$. One then can associate with this data for any $X, Y \in m$ the map $\Lambda(X)Y$, which is defined by
$$\Lambda(X)Y=\frac{1}{2}[X, Y]_m+U(X,Y)$$
where $U(X, Y)$ is defined by
$$2(U(X, Y), Z)=(X, [Z, Y]_m)+([Z, X]_m, Y)$$
I would now like to know what the geometric meaning of $\Lambda(X)Y)$ is. Can somebody tell me, how it can be interpreted in geometric terms?

Comment: Where did you come across $U(X,Y)$ and $\Lambda(X)Y$? That is, what is the source of this question?